# Wants to delete subfolders &files that contained specific portion of path name

Tags: windows, command-line

I would like to delete all subfolders and files that contained "2016\02" from that list

C:\A\2016\01

**C:\A\2016\02 <- This one**

C:\A\2016\03

C:\B\2017\01

**C:\B\2016\02 <- This one**

C:\B\2016\03

I have tried several string but it doesn't work. The thing is that i'm having more than 80 subfolders that contained the portion of the path "2016\02"

Comment: Please describe some of the things you tried.  Do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete. P.S. While you're editing your question, please delete the [delete] tag — it has been retired.

Comment: "I have tried several string but it doesn't work." - What exactly have you tried?  Remove the erroneous copied text from your other question.  You should also format your question.  Please be specific when you update your question, your question in it's current form, cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the PowerShell command to delete them:

get-childitem C:\ -include *2016\02.* -recurse | remove-item

Meanwhile, refer to this thread to try that small batch file:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/cd629ef5-af76-435b-a81c-cc4053716c68/delete-files-that-contain-specific-strings?forum=ITCG